# Как передать информацию через запущенные программы python

Tags: python

Запущена **программа A**, которая делает однотипные действия до её завершения.
Необходимо передать прогресс **A**, выражающийся в нескольких **int переменных** в запущенную **программу B**, учитывая, что **A** нельзя останавливать.

Самый простой способ, который я знаю и вижу - это создание **файла/sql** **A** каждые **n** секунд. И **B** будет просматривать последние сохранённые результаты.
Но это не практично.

Есть ли способ передать данные из **A** в **B** напрямую, желательно по запросу **B** и не занимая много времени?

Comment: Программа B может запустить в себе сервер на сокетах и по TCP получать команды или немного больше, но сделать вебсервер на HTTP и аналогично отправлять команды, но, например, в json/xml

Comment: Можно придумать что-то вроде демона как в линукс, который будет ждать сигнала от В и слушать какой-то порт.